# echo each wordin file get contents

Tags: php, arrays

Hello I have a text which written like this:

```
sh222022 HALIMA 20220329 1200 -21.4 82.5 S TS 45 994

wp932022 INVEST 20220329 1200 11.1 115.7 W DB 20 1008
```

I try separate word each but it didnt work

```
<?php

// get files content
$file_investraw = file_get_contents("./cache/data.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// put the data into arrays
$data_investraw = explode("\n", $file_investraw);

?>
```

I want the output like this, so how should I echo each word I like?:

```
sh222022

HALIMA

20220329

1200 

-21.4 

82.5 

S 

TS 

45 

994
```

or if I want to echo each word or each value, I cant separate it. Thank You

Comment: Likely you'll need `preg_split()` to do this as you have two delimiters (new-line AND space).

Answer (score 0):

you can do that like this.

```
 // get files content
 $file_investraw = file_get_contents("./cache/data.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

 // put the data into arrays and remove the empty element from array
 $data_investraw = array_filter(explode("\n", $file_data));

 // make the array filter data into string
 $data_investraw = implode(' ',$data_investraw);

 // explode the string into array
 $data_investraw = array_filter(explode(" ", $data_investraw));
```

this way you can achieve your desired output.